# Using a CMS with an external database

Tags: php, sql, database, drupal, expressionengine

I am looking at building an external site with a CMS, probably [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) or [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/). The problem is that our company already has a membership database that is designed to work with our existing enterprise software, currently the membership database consists of over 400k rows.

Migrating data from the database manually is not an option as modifications and new data must be accessible in real-time. Because the design of the external database will differ from the CMS's own I have decided the best way forward is to use two databases and force the CMS to use the external to read user information (cannot write to) and a local for everything else the CMS needs to do (read + write).

Is this feasible with these Drupal or ExpressionEngine? Ideally I need to be able to use `hooks` as I do not wan't to modify core CMS files. Sifting through the docs I am not able to find what I would hook into for ether CMS.

*(Note: I know it is possible, but I want to know if it's **feasible**).*

Finally if there is a better way of handling this situation please also chime in. Perhaps there is something at the database level to reference a column in an external database?

I'm clutching at straws someone can point me in the right direction I'm sure.

**Edit:** [Moodle](http://moodle.org/) has this functionality built in. Moodle is not suitable to my needs but perhaps their documentation will help you understand my issue better: [Moodle - External database authentication](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/External_database_authentication)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is to remain in an external database, then you probably want to look at creating a web service like an API that allows your external site to access the data. Queries to an external database or notoriously slow.

Comment: Unfortunately the queries must be done like this, the database's design and maintenance is the property of another team. Data modification should be kept on the CMS side.

Comment: If it's a third-party service then they'll most likely be an API. But if it's another department of your organisation then I'd strongly push for at least an API if it's essential. External database queries kill high-traffic websites.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Drupal (D)/ExpressionEnginge (EE) Expert.

For TYPO3 (which I know in depth) (and also for D & EE, I think)  you can write your own extension which fetches the user data from your membership database and stores them in the local frontend or backend user table for temp. authentication. 
We have build such a thing for a big financial institution even with single sign on and setting the corresponding rights depending on the remote groups.
There are plenty of TYPO3 extensions which can be used as an example.

The other possibility is to avoid again the real time feature and use a synchronization script on database level with checks the membership tables with the D or EE user table in e.g. 5min rhythm.

There is also the option to use a LDAP authentication.

If databases are all MySql then you can create a view which points to the remote membership table you only need to implement the correct columns.

It is always a bad idea to modify the core. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I always thought views where cached (I haven't actually used them), do they run the query each time or do they store a set of results from when they where created?

Answer (score 0):

There's an EE extension for working with external data in MySQL:  http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries .  I don't know what db you'll need to access or if this might be made to work with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

In ExpressionEngine there are six tables that contain Member and Member Group data (EE's lingo for users/user groups).

- exp_members
- exp_member_groups
- exp_member_bulletin_board
- exp_member_data
- exp_member_fields
- exp_member_homepage

In all likelihood you'd need to sync your user database with exp_members and exp_member_groups at a regular interval to make this happen. Trying to have EE connect to the external DB will likely get you in trouble fast.

If you are simply wanting access to your external database, you can write plugins that connect behind the scenes and make your data available inside your templates.

I worked a a Rails app once that pushed the Rails users to become EE members and shared sessions between them so users could view both systems and stay logged in.